# ngRoute not working / partials not loading

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, route-provider

I'm not getting any error messages, so I'm not sure what's wrong, but my partials do not load in the "main div" when I click on the links to them. I'm not totally sure if my controller and my route provider should be in separate js folders, but I saw a lot of examples of the controller and the route provider being in the same file, so I thought I'd try that. I'm running a SimpleHTTPServer to check this. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<html ng-init ng-app="vegApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="text/javascript" src="angular/js/angular-route.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>

</head>
<body ng-controller='itemListController'>  
 <div class="sidebar">
 <h3> <a href="#/login">log in</a></h3>
<h3> <a href="#/moreinfo">more info</a></h3>
<h3> <a href="#/recipes">recipes</a></h3>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
<ng-view=" "></ng-view>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS:

```
var vegApp = angular.module("vegApp", ["ngRoute", "itemListController"]);
var itemListController = angular.module("itemListController", []);

vegApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemlist.html',
        controller: 'itemListController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'itemListController'
    })
    .when('/moreinfo', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/moreinfo.html',
        controller: 'itemListController'
    })
    .when('/recipes', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/recipes.html',
        controller: 'itemListController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}
]);

var vegApp = angular.module('vegApp', [])
.controller('itemListController', function ($scope){
$scope.new_item = {};

$scope.items = [
        {imageurl: 'images/strawberry.png', type: 'strawberry', name: 'Herbert Strawberry', occupation: 'dogwalker', superpower: 'power-C boost'},
        {imageurl: 'images/blueberry.png', type: 'blueberry', name: 'Ulysses Blueberry', occupation: 'construction worker', superpower: 'super strength' },
    ];

});
```

Comment: Might be when you said `<ng-view = " ">` I've only seen it written as `<ng-view>` alone

Comment: you don't need [] in second angular.module

Comment: Have you checked the console if any error?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the updated code and try this if it works"

```
var vegApp = angular.module('vegApp',["ngRoute"])
.controller('itemListController', function ($scope){
$scope.new_item = {};

$scope.items = [
    {imageurl: 'images/strawberry.png', type: 'strawberry', name: 'Herbert Strawberry', occupation: 'dogwalker', superpower: 'power-C boost'},
    {imageurl: 'images/blueberry.png', type: 'blueberry', name: 'Ulysses Blueberry', occupation: 'construction worker', superpower: 'super strength' },
];

});

vegApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/itemlist.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.when('/moreinfo', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/moreinfo.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.when('/recipes', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/recipes.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
});
 }
 ]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. The only error message I get points to the angular-route.js file I have in my script tag at the top of my HTML. It says GET http://localhost:8000/text/javascript...do you think something is wrong with that script tag? I have that file in my directory. It's frustrating, because your code makes complete sense to me...

Comment: I'm seeing that my angular-route file is version 1.2.10, and my angular.js file is version 1.3.14...could that be the problem???

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

in place of

```
<ng-view=" "></ng-view>
```

in index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the href as this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <h3> <a href="#/login">log in</a></h3>
   <h3> <a href="#/moreinfo">more info</a></h3>
   <h3> <a href="#/recipes">recipes</a></h3>
</div>
```

You should use the following instead:

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <h3> <a href="#login">log in</a></h3>
   <h3> <a href="#moreinfo">more info</a></h3>
   <h3> <a href="#recipes">recipes</a></h3>
</div>
```

The '/' would make route provider to not be able to find the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining your module in app.js . You are over-writing the routing logic by re defining vegApp .

Module redefinition fails silently in Angular : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1779

Re-work your app.js as follows :

```
    var vegApp = angular.module("vegApp", ["ngRoute", "itemListController"]);
    var itemListController = angular.module("itemListController", []);

    vegApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/itemlist.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.when('/moreinfo', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/moreinfo.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.when('/recipes', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/recipes.html',
    controller: 'itemListController'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
});
}
    ]);

    vegApp.controller('itemListController', function ($scope){
    $scope.new_item = {};

    $scope.items = [
    {imageurl: 'images/strawberry.png', type: 'strawberry', name: 'Herbert Strawberry', occupation: 'dogwalker', superpower: 'power-C boost'},
    {imageurl: 'images/blueberry.png', type: 'blueberry', name: 'Ulysses Blueberry', occupation: 'construction worker', superpower: 'super strength' },
];

});
```